# I made npm component, calling it into another program, when When I importing through an error

Tags: reactjs, npm, components

I made npm component, calling it into another program, when I importing through an error. But I had already setup all the configuration of babel and preset.

I can also change the card-counter-component component if required, I made it just for demo purpose, because I have to start making some component.

```
Compiled with problems:
×
ERROR in ./node_modules/card-counter-component/Card.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel- 
loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /Users/org/Documents/Demos/use-mycard-component/node_modules/card- 
counter-component/Card.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently 
enabled (17:7):

15 |
16 |   return (
> 17 |       <div className="card">
 |       ^
18 |       <Message label = "React is a free and open-source front-end JavaScript 
library for building user interfaces based on components. It is maintained by Meta 
and a community of individual developers and companies. React can be used to develop 
single-page, mobile, or server-rendered applications with frameworks like Next.js." 
/>
19 |       <h1>Counter: {counter}</h1>
20 |       <div className='button-container'>

Add @babel/preset-react (https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/packages/babel- 
preset-react) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx 
(https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/packages/babel-plugin-syntax-jsx) to the 
'plugins' section to enable parsing.
at instantiate (/Users/org/Documents/Demos/use-mycard- 
component/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:63:32)
at constructor (/Users/org/Documents/Demos/use-mycard- 
component/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:358:12)
at Parser.raise (/Users/org/Documents/Demos/use-mycard- 
component/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:3255:19)
at Parser.expectOnePlugin (/Users/org/Documents/Demos/use-mycard- 
component/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:3301:18)
at Parser.parseExprAtom (/Users/org/Documents/Demos/use-mycard- 
component/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11245:18)
at Parser.parseExprSubscripts (/Users/org/Documents/Demos/use-mycard- 
component/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10890:23)
at Parser.parseUpdate (/Users/org/Documents/Demos/use-mycard- 
component/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10873:21)
at Parser.parseMaybeUnary (/Users/org/Documents/Demos/use-mycard- 
component/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10849:23)
at Parser.parseMaybeUnaryOrPrivate (/Users/org/Documents/Demos/use-mycard- 
 component/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10687:61)
at Parser.parseExprOps (/Users/org/Documents/Demos/use-mycard- 
component/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10692:23)
at Parser.parseMaybeConditional (/Users/org/Documents/Demos/use-mycard- 
component/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10669:23)
at Parser.parseMaybeAssign (/Users/org/Documents/Demos/use-mycard- 
component/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10630:21)
at /Users/org/Documents/Demos/use-mycard- 
component/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10600:39
at Parser.allowInAnd (/Users/org/Documents/Demos/use-mycard- 
component/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:12280:12)
at Parser.parseMaybeAssignAllowIn (/Users/org/Documents/Demos/use-mycard- 
component/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10600:17)
at Parser.parseParenAndDistinguishExpression (/Users/org/Documents/Demos/use- 
mycard-component/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11513:28)
at Parser.parseExprAtom (/Users/org/Documents/Demos/use-mycard- 
component/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11164:23)
at Parser.parseExprSubscripts (/Users/org/Documents/Demos/use-mycard- 
component/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10890:23)
at Parser.parseUpdate (/Users/org/Documents/Demos/use-mycard-component/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10873:21)
at Parser.parseMaybeUnary (/Users/org/Documents/Demos/use-mycard-component/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10849:23)
at Parser.parseMaybeUnaryOrPrivate (/Users/org/Documents/Demos/use-mycard-component/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10687:61)
at Parser.parseExprOps (/Users/org/Documents/Demos/use-mycard-component/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10692:23)
at Parser.parseMaybeConditional (/Users/org/Documents/Demos/use-mycard-component/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10669:23)
at Parser.parseMaybeAssign (/Users/org/Documents/Demos/use-mycard-component/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10630:21)
at Parser.parseExpressionBase (/Users/org/Documents/Demos/use-mycard-component/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10584:23)
at /Users/org/Documents/Demos/use-mycard-component/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10580:39
at Parser.allowInAnd (/Users/org/Documents/Demos/use-mycard-component/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:12275:16)
at Parser.parseExpression
```

Please help me, how to fix this issue. thanks